# Is it safe to update a field value direclty on the Database

Tags: 7, database

When updating a field attached to a node, Drupal calls several hooks and add a record on the appropriate field revision. Is there any risk if I by-pass this process and update the field value via a sql query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not recommended, there is a way of doing this using `field_attach_update` which should give you the performance benefit of not saving the whole node while using drupal api. Example:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->id = $id_value;          // node id
$node->type = $bundle_value;  // aka content type

$node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
field_attach_update('node', $node);
```

Sources:

[updating field value of a content type with query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98566/updating-field-value-of-a-content-type-with-query)

https://www.urbaninsight.com/2011/10/24/saving-nodes-fields-without-saving-node-itself

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7

Comment: Thnx, but can I know why it's not recommended ? As It's currently working properly and I'll need to know if it's safe or not

Comment: 2 main reasons @sel_space: it makes your code prone to bugs that the Api would otherwise handle for you, but perhaps most importantly, a direct db method does not clear appropriate caches, potentially leaving you with stale content